# MouseOver on all days after today in Jquery's FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, jquery

Is it possible to make a mouseover event only on days that come after the actual day in FullCalendar?

If yes, how could I do that? 
I just want to show the cursor "pointer" over the cells of the days after today...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table cell (td element) for today has the class 'fc-today'.  You need to run some jQuery to set the css on all the tds after this in the table.  This can be done by putting this code in a function and assigning it to the option 'viewDisplay' on initialising the fullCalendar.  I think this jQuery code should do it:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
...,
  viewDisplay: function (view) {
    if (view.start > new Date())
      $('.fc-view').find('td').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    else if (view.end < new Date())
      $('.fc-view').find('td').css('cursor', 'auto');
    else {
      $('.fc-view').find('td').css('cursor', 'auto');
      $('.fc-today').nextAll('td').css('cursor', 'pointer');
      $('.fc-today').closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('td').css('cursor', 'pointer');
    }
  },
...
});
```

Comment: It works for the current month but, if I change the month, it doesn't work because .fc-today doesn't exist anymore... =S

Comment: Hi I edited the code above, I had the first two conditions the wrong way round, also clarified how to set this up.  That definitely works, I've checked it.  Thanks.

Comment: I will check it tomorrow. Thanks =).